# Dealing with drawRect multiple calls

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

I discovered that my drawRect is being called more than once. Unfortunately this had the unfortunate side-effect of double-drawing everything because all my subviews are drawn in drawRect (I'm s strict atheist w.r.t. Interface Builder).

What is the best way to deal with a multiple calls to drawrect? A flag to check if it's being called again? Or clear the whole view and redraw from scratch (as I have done?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "your subviews are drawn in drawRect"? If you mean that you're putting calls to -addSubview: in your drawRect, don't. Move those to a more appropriate place that gets called only when it needs to (probably the -initWithFrame: method for your view if the subviews are *always* there), and use drawRect only to do custom drawing.

Strictly speaking, being called multiple times is the entire point of -drawRect. It's called to update small parts of your view when needed. It's actually called quite often if you're updating your view (moving it around, updating the superview, etc.), so it should be as simple and fast as possible to avoid performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

When UIKit calls `drawRect:`, the graphics context set up to draw into should already be cleared for you (unless you have set the `clearsContextBeforeDrawing` property to `NO`). Are you perhaps calling `drawRect:` manually instead of calling `setNeedsDisplay`/`setNeedsDisplayInRect:`?

Also, each view is responsible for drawing *only* its own content and *not* the content of its subviews.

Comment: What if a view has a UIButton for instance? Does the view have to redraw the UIButton? IS UIButton part of the content of UIView

Comment: A view can't "have a UIButton" it can contain a UIButton in that the button would be its subview. Subviews are not considered part of a view's content.